# How can I stop bot to crawl and index my CDN version of website?

Tags: indexing, web-crawler

I am using Cloud front as a CDN for my website. My website has two versions. One is live website  mydomain.com/ and second origin.mydomain.com/ as a CDN version. I want to ask how can I stop search engines to crawl and indexing my CDN version content.

For SEO I am using Rank Math and added canonical URL for indexing master page on live website.

Google page indexing report is showing issues with origin version pages like Crawled - currently not indexed and Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user.

Is there any way I can stop crawling and indexing for my CDN version.